# Can we convert a weak entity to strong entity in an ER-Model?

Tags: database, data-modeling

For and ER Model, can a weak entity be converted to strong entity by adding additional attributes? What is the use of weak entities?

Comment: cf. [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is once of example for me , I hope this image is useful.